# C# enabling or disabling control

Tags: c#, isenabled

So, I'm losing my mind over a bug in my software.

I have this code, I use it 2 times in my software, the other function similar (with a different name) works normally. But this one is inverted...

I mean by that : Instead of enabling the controls when the groupbox.text contains "INC", it disable them.

Any idea on what is going on?

```
`private void Enable_disableSTM()
    {
        if (STM_groupBox.Text.Contains("INC"))
        {
            STM_radioButton_appel.Enabled = true;
            STM_radioButton_autre.Enabled = true;
            STM_radioButton_resolution.Enabled = true;
            STM_Textbox_SR.Enabled = true;
            STM_textBox_remarque.Enabled = true;
            STM_Dropdown_Sendto.Enabled = true;
            STM_pictureBox_Boutonenvoyer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            STM_radioButton_appel.Enabled = false;
            STM_radioButton_autre.Enabled = false;
            STM_radioButton_resolution.Enabled = false;
            STM_Textbox_SR.Enabled = false;
            STM_textBox_remarque.Enabled = false;
            STM_Dropdown_Sendto.Enabled = false;
            STM_pictureBox_Boutonenvoyer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }    `
```

Edit :

Like I said, in my software I have this other function that is working fine. I tried also to change my IF to     `STM_Textbox_reademail.Text != ""`     and it's still not working correctly. It's inverted. Enabling when it should not and Disabling too.

```
`if (SQ_TextBox_reademail.Text != "")
        {
            SQ_radioButton_appel.Enabled = true;
            SQ_radioButton_autre.Enabled = true;
            SQ_radioButton_resolution.Enabled = true;
            SQ_Textbox_SR.Enabled = true;
            SQ_textBox_remarque.Enabled = true;
            SQ_Dropdown_Sendto.Enabled = true;
            SQ_pictureBox_Boutonenvoyer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SQ_radioButton_appel.Enabled = false;
            SQ_radioButton_autre.Enabled = false;
            SQ_radioButton_resolution.Enabled = false;
            SQ_Textbox_SR.Enabled = false;
            SQ_textBox_remarque.Enabled = false;
            SQ_Dropdown_Sendto.Enabled = false;
            SQ_pictureBox_Boutonenvoyer.Enabled = false;
        }   `
```

Edit 2 : Okay... I figured out something that works. I'm calling my function at a different place now and it's working. Still does not make sense why I can call the other one at the same place and it works but this one doesn't... but hey... now it works! thanks all!

Comment: Is the string inside the textbox contains "INC" ? remember that contains is case sensitive

Comment: Usually these problems are easily solved using the debugger. Just put a breakpoint at the first line of this code and when hit look at the variables involved and follow the code flow

Comment: as Steve suggested. I would either put a breakpoint for debugging or print out a console line to check the case in if statement

Comment: Another way of looking at this is to create some code that calculates the enabled state (using @TiagoSilva's answer): `bool isEnabled = STM_groupBox.Text.IndexOf("INC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`, and then just set all of your controls' `Enabled` property to that variable.  That way, you only list them out once.  You could also create a collection of controls and loop through the collection.

Comment: Okay, so basically, I had this other one that was working fine : 

`if (SQ_TextBox_reademail.Text != "")
{
SQ_radioButton_appel.Enabled = true;
...
}
else
{
SQ_radioButton_appel.Enabled = false;
...
}`

And I tried also my other one to put exactly the same and just change my controls. for some reason, one works, the other one does not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I figured out something that works. I'm calling my function at a different place now and it's working. Still does not make sense why I can call the other one at the same place and it works but this one doesn't... but hey... now it works! thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are checking if a string contains the "INC" word in a case sensitive way the solution is changing the if statement to check in the string the inc word ignoring the case :

```
    private void Enable_disableSTM()
    {
        if (STM_groupBox.Text.IndexOf("INC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;)
        {
            STM_radioButton_appel.Enabled = true;
            STM_radioButton_autre.Enabled = true;
            STM_radioButton_resolution.Enabled = true;
            STM_Textbox_SR.Enabled = true;
            STM_textBox_remarque.Enabled = true;
            STM_Dropdown_Sendto.Enabled = true;
            STM_pictureBox_Boutonenvoyer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            STM_radioButton_appel.Enabled = false;
            STM_radioButton_autre.Enabled = false;
            STM_radioButton_resolution.Enabled = false;
            STM_Textbox_SR.Enabled = false;
            STM_textBox_remarque.Enabled = false;
            STM_Dropdown_Sendto.Enabled = false;
            STM_pictureBox_Boutonenvoyer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```